# QT EGLFS not showing Text

Tags: qt, qt5

I am having trouble getting the QT EGLFS platform to show text with the basic UI controls... Any idea what I might be missing?

Here is the code:

```
/*
// Shows text:
sudo Xorg &
clang++-3.8 -g --std=c++11 -fPIC -Wall \
  -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/ \
  test1.cpp \
  -l Qt5Core  \
  -l Qt5Gui \
  -l Qt5Widgets \
  -o test1 &&
sudo DISPLAY=:0 HOME=/tmp ./test1
sudo killall Xorg

// Does not show text:
clang++-3.8 -g --std=c++11 -fPIC -Wall \
  -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/ \
  test1.cpp \
  -l Qt5Core  \
  -l Qt5Gui \
  -l Qt5Widgets \
  -o test1 &&
sudo HOME=/tmp ./test1 --platform eglfs

*/
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);

    QOpenGLWidget root_widget;
    root_widget.setAutoFillBackground(true);
    root_widget.show();

    QTextEdit text_box1(&root_widget);
    text_box1.setPlainText("INITIAL TEXT");
    text_box1.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 50);
    text_box1.show();

    QPushButton button1(&root_widget);
    button1.setGeometry(0, 60, 500, 50);
    button1.setText("Test1");
    button1.show();

   return  app->exec();

}
```

When I just use Xorg I get this (the text shows up as expected):
[image: the text shows up as expected]

But if I use EGLFS, this is what I get (No text):[image: no text]

EDIT:
I am on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04, I am using qt5 as packaged by ubuntu, Ubuntu reports package version: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1

Comment: Which version of Qt? How did you build it? Which platform?

Comment: @peppe:  I am on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04, I am using qt5 as packaged by ubuntu, Ubuntu reports package version: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1